# Rc::downgrade does not seem to drop ownership in a Rust program

Tags: rust, struct, reference, weak-references

I'm trying to create a simple minesweeper in Rust. For this I want to create a `Grid` object, holding all `Case` objects. When a `Case` is clicked, it notifies the `Grid`.

I want all cases to have a `Weak` reference to the grid. Why does the borrow checker prevent me from doing so?

Quoting the doc:

> `Weak` is a version of `Rc` that holds a non-owning reference to the managed allocation.

`link` marked by the comment should not be owning the grid, yet the compiler tells me the value has been moved.

```rust
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

pub struct Grid {
    dimensions: (usize, usize),
    n_mines: usize,
    content: Vec<Vec<Case>>,
}

impl Grid {
    pub fn new(dimensions: (usize, usize), n_mines: usize) -> Self {
        let (n, m) = dimensions;
        let mines: Vec<Vec<Case>> = Vec::with_capacity(m);

        let mut grid = Self {
            dimensions: dimensions,
            n_mines: n_mines,
            content: mines,
        };

        let link = Rc::new(grid);
        let link = Rc::downgrade(&link); // here link loses the ownership of grid, right ?

        println!("{}\n", grid.n_mines);
        for i in 0..m {
            let mut line: Vec<Case> = Vec::with_capacity(n);
            for j in 0..n {
                let case = Case::new_with_parent((i, j), Weak::clone(&link));
                line.push(case)
            }
            grid.content.push(line);
        }

        grid
    }

    pub fn click_neighbours(&mut self, coordinates: (usize, usize)) {
        let surrouding = vec![(0, 0), (0, 1)]; // not a real implementation
        for coord in surrouding {
            self.content[coord.0][coord.1].click();
        }
    }
}

pub struct Case {
    pub coordinates: (usize, usize),
    parent: Weak<Grid>,
}

impl Case {
    pub fn new_with_parent(coordinates: (usize, usize), parent: Weak<Grid>) -> Case {
        Self {
            coordinates: coordinates,
            parent: parent,
        }
    }

    pub fn click(&mut self) {
        match self.parent.upgrade() {
            Some(x) => x.click_neighbours(self.coordinates),
            None => println!("whatever, not the issue here"),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let grid = Grid::new((10, 10), 5);
}
```

I tried multiple variation around enforcement of borrowing rules at *runtime* by putting the grid content into a `RefCell`. I'm also currently trying to adapt the Observer design pattern implementation in Rust to my problem, but without any success so far.

Answer (score 0):

1. `grid` is moved into `Rc::new`, so you can't use it any longer. You'll have to return that `Rc` from `Grid::new`
2. You can't modify the value within the `Rc` while you hold `Weak` references to it. So you'll have to wrap the inner value in a `RefCell` as well. Otherwise the loop where you create the `line`s is impossible

Here's a valid version of your code:

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

pub struct Grid {
    dimensions: (usize, usize),
    n_mines: usize,
    content: Vec<Vec<Case>>,
}

impl Grid {
    pub fn new(dimensions: (usize, usize), n_mines: usize) -> Rc<RefCell<Self>> {
        let (n, m) = dimensions;
        let mines: Vec<Vec<Case>> = Vec::with_capacity(m);

        let grid = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Self {
            dimensions: dimensions,
            n_mines: n_mines,
            content: mines,
        }));
        let link_weak = Rc::downgrade(&grid);

        println!("{}\n", grid.borrow().n_mines);

        {
            // avoid repeatedly calling `borrow_mut` in the loop
            let grid_mut = &mut *grid.borrow_mut();

            for i in 0..m {
                let mut line: Vec<Case> = Vec::with_capacity(n);
                for j in 0..n {
                    let case = Case::new_with_parent((i, j), Weak::clone(&link_weak));
                    line.push(case)
                }
                grid_mut.content.push(line);
            }
        }

        grid
    }

    pub fn click_neighbours(&mut self, coordinates: (usize, usize)) {
        let surrouding = vec![(0, 0), (0, 1)]; // not a real implementation
        for coord in surrouding {
            self.content[coord.0][coord.1].click();
        }
    }
}

pub struct Case {
    pub coordinates: (usize, usize),
    parent: Weak<RefCell<Grid>>,
}

impl Case {
    pub fn new_with_parent(coordinates: (usize, usize), parent: Weak<RefCell<Grid>>) -> Case {
        Self {
            coordinates: coordinates,
            parent: parent,
        }
    }

    pub fn click(&mut self) {
        match self.parent.upgrade() {
            Some(grid) => grid.borrow_mut().click_neighbours(self.coordinates),
            None => println!("whatever, not the issue here"),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let grid = Grid::new((10, 10), 5);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d063e64f72a33199d1998cb8469d7464)

Answer (score 0):

There is a misconception here, by moving the grid here:

```rust
let link = Rc::new(grid);
```

you irrevocably destroy `grid`, nothing you do to `link` brings back your old `grid`.
The only thing that could do so would be to use [`Rc::try_unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.try_unwrap) to unwrap `link` and assign it back to `grid`,
but that's not what you want to do here.

Instead you can additionally wrap the grid in a `RefCell` like so:

```rust
let grid = Rc::new(RefCell::new(grid));
```

Which in then lets you edit the grid inside with `borrow_mut`:

```rust
grid.borrow_mut().content.push(line);
```

You can see in [PitaJ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75099831/442760) how the full listing of your code should look like.